# Output of a stable LTI system

Tags: fourier-transform, linear-systems, impulse-response, stability, signal-energy

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a stable LTI system. Is it true that if input has finite energy then output also has finite energy? I'm not sure about that. We know that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|h(t)|dt\lt\infty \tag{1}$$Where $h(t)$ is the impulse response. Also we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|y(t)|dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|Y(s)|ds = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|X(s)||H(s)|ds \tag{2}$$Since $y(t) = \mathcal{L}(x(t)) = x(t)\star h(t)$ which implies $Y(s) = X(s)H(s)$. Applying Cauchy–Schwarz inequality to $(2)$, $$\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|X(s)||H(s)|ds\right)^2 \le  \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|X(s)|^2ds\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|H(s)|^2ds\right) \tag{3}$$We know that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|X(s)|^2ds = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x(t)|^2dt<\infty$$Since input is an energy signal but $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|H(s)|^2ds$$doesn't necessarily exists. So is this indicates that we can find a counterexample to the statement or we can prove that by other methods?

**Edit:** [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867638/square-integrability-of-an-absolute-integrable-function) is a counterexample which shows $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|dt\lt \infty \nRightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt\lt \infty$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong. First of all, I've made a silly mistake  $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|y(t)|dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|Y(s)|ds$$which is clearly false. Let $y(t) = x(t)\star h(t)$. We have $$E_y = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|y(t)|^2dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|Y(s)|^2ds = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|H(s)X(s)|^2ds = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|H(s)|^2|X(s)|^2ds$$Also we have $$|H(s)| = \left|\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2\pi ist}h(t)dt \right | \le \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|e^{-2\pi ist}h(t)|dt =  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|h(t)|dt \lt\infty$$So  $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}:\ \ |H(s)|\le M$ for all $s$. This means that $|H(s)|^2\le M^2$ and then $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|H(s)|^2|X(s)|^2ds\le M^2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|X(s)|^2ds$$By assumption $$E_x = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x(t)|^2dt=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|X(s)|^2ds$$The result is $$E_y \le M^2 E_g$$

Comment: Help me understand this. Assume $x(t) = t$. I would say that $x(t) < \infty$ for all $t$ (I _would_ say, though, that $x(t) \rightarrow \infty$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$). However, in this case there is no $M$ such that  $x(t) < M$ for all $t$.

Comment: @MBaz Note that by a bounded function we mean there exists $M\gt 0$ such that $|x(t)|\le M$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Here $|H(s)|$ is bounded by $M = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|h(t)|dt$ and so $|H(s)|\le M$ for all $s$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019989/can-we-say-a-function-is-unbounded-when-we-mean-its-tending-to-infinity) for better explanation.

Comment: Looks good to me -- at least using "engineering" math. I think this is a nice result.

Comment: @MBaz Thank you so much for reading my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rough outline of proof:

1. A (real-valued) system that's IIR has an impulse response that's $h(t) \ne 0$ for infinitely long
2. Since $\lvert h(t)\rvert \ge h(t) > 0$ for infinity, it follows that this impulse response doesn't have finite energy
3. there are stable LTI IIR systems

Comment: Could you elaborate more, please?

Comment: I could, but I don't know where it'd be necessary. Could you point out what specifically you're unclear about?

Comment: I couldn't follow your reasoning. First of all, why IIR system came into the solution? Second, what do you mean by "for infinity"? Honestly, I didn't understand what you proposed. Are you trying to prove the statement or disproving it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's possible for $h(t) > 0$ for all $t$ but its integral to be finite, if $h(t) \rightarrow 0$ fast enough. For example, a Gaussian pulse.

Comment: @MBaz Do you think that the statement is true?

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct since it seems to ignore "stability". I think stabiility implies tta the impulse resoonse can be bounded by some exponential decay  which I think has finite energy.

Comment: @Hilmar That seems intuitively correct since $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|h(t)|dt$ is finite but the question is how to make that idea rigorous.

Comment: @S.H.W If the integral of $|h(t)|$ is finite, then the integral of $|h(t)|^2$ should be finite too, right? If so, then the integral of $|H(s)|^2$ would be finite.

Comment: @MBaz That's what I couldn't prove(and maybe it's false). Is it true that if $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |h(t)|dt$ is finite then $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |h(t)|^2dt$ is also finite?

Comment: I don't know if I can prove it, but my first try would be like this: break up $|h(t)|$ into regions where it's $>0$ and others where its $<0$. The integral of $|h(t)|^2$ of the regions where it's larger than 1 will be larger but still finite. The integral of the regions where it's less than 1 will be even smaller. So, the total is still finite. We can do this because $h(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$, which means that $h(t)>1$ only in a finite support.

Comment: @MBaz Unfortunately, that's not true. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3867638/square-integrability-of-an-absolute-integrable-function) for counterexample.

Comment: Interesting... can you use that function as a counterexample?

Comment: @MBaz I tried to find an energy signal which leads to a non-energy signal as output, for that system, but it wasn't successful.

Comment: @MBaz I've added an answer which might be the correct solution. Have a look if you want.